# Protocols supported by Safari browser

Tags: safari, url-scheme

What are the URL **protocols** (i.e. `http` in `http://www.google.com`) supported by *Safari* browser?

Excluding those who are not handled by third party applications, such as `mailto:`.

For example some of the known protocols are: `http`, `http`, `ftp`, `feed`.

Can I get a list of those anywhere?

**EDIT :**
I got the list in here:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml

But I don't know that by default which of them are opend by *Safari* web browser and not any third party application.